# Matlab: Titration algorithm for reaction time?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

Let's say I have a simple experiment where I show a white circle on the screen, and I have to press a button while the circle is still displayed on the screen for it to be a 'hit'. I want to titrate the time that the circle is on screen, such that for every subsequent trial, there's a certain probability of getting a 'hit' (let's say 70%).

I currently have three main variables, (1) the initial time the cue is displayed on screen, (2) an array where there's a 1 if hit, and 0 if miss, and (3) an array of reaction times for each trial. What is the best algorithm/method for such a titration?

Comment: use `tstart=tic` , and `tend=toc`...  read more here http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the transformed up-down method (see http://dx.doi.org/10.1121/1.1912375). To get 70.7% correct, every time they get it wrong (a miss) increase the duration by a step size, and every time they get it right twice in a row decrease the duration by the same step size.